# NodeJS Cheerio Scraping li tags always returns NULL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to zero in on the URL contained within the li tags on the page in my URL variable. It should be simple, but I can't get it to work. I get the correct number of elements, but they are all blank. text() returns '' & html() returns null. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');

function getHistory(){
  let url = 'http://coinmarketcap.com/historical/';
  request(url,(error,response,html)=>{
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('li.text-center').each((i,element)=>{
      var omg = $(this).html();
      console.log(omg);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because this code is in an arrow function (which retains the lexical value of this, not what `.each()` sets it to), the value of `this` is not set to what you want it to be.  If you change this:

```
var omg = $(this).html();
```

to this:

```
var omg = $(element).html();
```

You will see the HTML you were expecting.

Note, you may also be able to change the arrow function to a regular function and then whatever value of `this` that `.each()` sets will be in effect.

---

If what you really want is the `href`, then you should target the `<a>` tag with your selector and get the actual `href` attribute from it.  You could do that like this:

```
function getHistory(){
  let url = 'http://coinmarketcap.com/historical/';
  request(url,(error,response,html)=>{
    let $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('li.text-center a').each((i,element)=>{
      let omg = $(element).attr('href');
      console.log(omg);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend, you saved me hours of frustration!

Comment: OMG, so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

That’s because you are referring to `this` in an *arrow function*, which doesn’t make its own `this`.